# How to select a default branch when git pull

Tags: git

I have 2 folders on my server and they have the same files or codes. the uat folder and staging folder. Those folders have the same branch. When I run `git pull` in each folder, the master branch will be used. I just want to separate the staging folder. If I run `git pull` on the staging folder, the staging branch will be used not the master branch.

I only know basic git commands like push, commits, and pull, but I'm new to adding a setup like that scenario.

Comment: I am assuming that you have a remote repository (GitHub, Azure DevOps, Bitbucket, etc). What was the default branch in that remote repository? From my understanding, the default branch on local should follow the branch on remote. Also, the default branch has been changed to "main" in new versions of Git, and you should check which branch is the default in your remote.